# SSL Pinning with AFNetworking 3 in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, openssl, afnetworking, afnetworking-3, certificate-pinning

I am trying to achieve achieve SSL pinning with AFNetworking 3 library.

I went through the documentation of AFSecurityPolicy but I didn't get any information about ssl pinning by using **AFSSLPinningModePublicKey**. Here is the code snippet I am using

```
AFHTTPSessionManager * manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];


AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey];
sessionManager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my-certificate" ofType:@"cer"];
NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];
sessionManager.securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates = @[certData];
```

**Output :**

I can see the certificate being picked up from the bundle while running in debug mode but then

I am getting Error as :

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

**Investigation :**

1. validateCertificateChain : parameter is not there anymore for
       versions 3+ in AFNetworking . **Does that mean I will have to
       pinning all the certificates of my certificate chain ?**

I might be creating my certificates (.cer) wrongly . Can you please let me know how to extract .cer from the url ?

I have used the following commands in my mac terminal

```
echo "Get HTTP/1.0" | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.xxxx.xx:443 > mycertificateinpem.pem

openssl x509 -inform PEM -in mycertificateinpem.pem -outform DER -out my-certificate.cer
```

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve the issue.. I was making double instances of the afsecurity policy . That’s the reason one instance was overriding the other.

Please Note : AFNetworking 3.0 can be used to pin the intermediate certificate . It doesn’t verify the whole chain. :)

Comment: I am getting the same error code(-999) but I doubt I am making two instances. How can I check AFNetworking two instances?